# Is there a way to determine what guild a userUpdate event is coming from?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm setting up server logs on my Discord.js bot and I'm currently stuck at the userUpdate event. I want it to be able to work for two servers. So if a user update occurred in server A, send the logging message to the server A logging channel. If a user update occurred in server B, send the logging message to the server B logging channel. If a user update occured in both server A and server B (the user is in both servers), send the logging message to both logging channels.

I've tried this:

```
if (newUser.guild.id === '<guildid>') {
     client.channels.cache.get('<channelid>').send(embed);
}
```

But it doesn't work. It returns an error "Can't find ID of undefined". I looked at the Discord.js documentation and there is no guild property under User, which is obviously why I am getting this error.

Is there any way to make this work?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`userUpdate` properties are from the class `user` so there is no chance that the update occurred in a `Guild`.

You can try the `GuildMemberUpdate` which returns `GuildMember` so it will have a `Guild` property.

Comment: Can you determine avatar/username/discriminator changes with guildMemberUpdate?

Comment: Yes since the event returns two parameters - `oldMember` and `newMember` since they both belong from the `GuildMember` class so it has an `user` property from this property you can compare between the `oldMember` and `newMember` to detect the changes.